# All UITableViewControllers in app allow scrolling up beyond the beginning and past the end of the list.

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

After using my app for several minutes, all table views in the app start behaving strangely. The scrolling becomes jerky and you can scroll the list above the start and below the end. What could be causing this?

[image: normal tableview]
[image: scrolls way above top and stays]
[image: scrolls way beyond end and stays]

Comment: try using tableView.contentInset = .zero and tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = .zero in swift 3.0 or use tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero and tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets  = UIEdgeInsetsZero in objective-C

Comment: @Sanket I've already set the properties as you described, and the tableviews behave as expected at first. It's only after running the app for a little while that the problem starts occurring. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a recursive UiView Animation that was preventing a viewcontroller from being deallocated. After loading and not unloading that VC a few times, the main thread began to bog down.